# Change of return flight ticket - pay for luggage again?

Tags: air-travel, luggage

Changing a return ticket for low-cost air flights (ex. Wizz Air) requires paying half of the original price. However, if you have previously paid for a certain amount of luggage, do you have to pay for it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the information provided online it seems that you may only have to pay for a date change which is as follows:

> Flight change fee
>
> 50% of the original fare. Minimum and maximum amount of the fee is
>   shown in the table.
>
> via wizzair.com   Per flight, per passenger   €10.00 - €60.00 / £9.00 -
>   £53.00

https://wizzair.com/en-GB/useful_information/service_fees#ChangeFees

This accounts for the original fare only. The baggage which you purchased is a separate add-on just like WIZZ Xpress priority boarding etc; so they won't account to date changes. If you are still not satisfied you should contact there customer service @ 0330 977 0444 (UK Number)